# Trying to create a search and display app

Tags: ios, search

I'm trying to create an app in which i have information set up with-in the app and when the user searches for the information it displays it on the screen. So for example say you search for "Hamburger" in the app; the app looks into it's information and displays it.
Can anyone explain to me how to go about doing this or at least point me to a source that can.

Thanks

Comment: This seems very generalized. Are you asking about effective ways to process and display searched information?

Comment: yes. but information that is within the app. Not a web search. @a sandwhich

Comment: There are many ways to go about doing that. Displaying and searching are also two different things, so I suggest you look through some of the various ways you want to display the search results and see how you might achieve that with the given ios tools. Then come back with slightly more specific questions. This is a tad broad for a single SO question.

Comment: agree, worry about presenting the information first.  how to search will be more obvious when you have your information represented in a app.  e.g. it's likely to be in an array, then you can read about many array searching methods in NSArray class reference.  (or maybe it's huge and you can read up on wikipedia about indexing).

Comment: thanks guys! i'll definitely be back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in framework for doing this would be [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UISearchDisplayController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are many tutorials our there to get you started for using these controllers ([here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view), [here](http://blog.patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html) and [here](http://cocoabob.net/?p=67)).

Of course there are many custom ways to accomplish the same tasks, but this would be a good place to start if you are just getting started.